# HDMI port on ViewSonic VX2753mh-LED display not working

Tags: windows

I bought a used slim PS3 and when I tried to output it's video to my [ViewSonic 27" VX2753mh-LED](https://www.viewsonic.com/eu/products/archive/VX2753mh-LED.php) display it fails. So I thought maybe the cable is damaged, changed two other cables but no luck.

Then I tried to plug the other port HDMI cable — which was inserted into PC graphic card — and it worked. Used the very same cable into other HDMI port on ViewSonic display and it didn't work.

I thought maybe the other port is faulty and took it to a repair shop. He checked it and said it's okay. Even I saw Xbox output on that same HDMI port.

Came back home only to find the similar issue. What's wrong here?

I can't get display via HDMI 1 on my display.

Comment: Very strange. Have you tried to do some really basic things like clean the connectors on the display. Or at least check if there is any dust or dirt there.

Comment: Yup the repairing shop guy did clean the connectors..

Comment: Do you know the exact make and model of the ViewSonic display? This seems like it might be something as simple as HDMI versions. Technically that should not be an issue, but it sometimes is a factor.

Comment: VX-2753mh is the model.

Comment: Good to know. From what I can see, [that model supports HDMI 1.3](https://www.viewsonic.com/eu/products/archive/VX2753mh-LED.php) but checking the [PS3 specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3#Technical_specifications) I see that supports HDMI 1.4. Wonder if you can downgrade the video output in the PS3 and see if that works? Past that I don’t know what other advice I can pass along.

Comment: Basic troubleshooting: check if the PS3 isn't faulty by connecting it to a different display.

Comment: Well okay forget it, Now I don't know how can I use the audio from PS3 on the same LED monitor. it has a audio output jack but my Zoltrix speakers don't have any input jack.